# because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: javascript, html, meta-tags, content-security-policy

I am in a plain html file.

I have three cdn's in my application and one static server file:

```
 <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/static/js/main.js"></script>
```

And I am getting the following errors:

```js
  localhost/:35 Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://localhost:* 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.

localhost/:1 Refused to load the script 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

localhost/:1 Refused to load the script 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://localhost:* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

localhost/:1 Refused to load the script 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

localhost/:1 Refused to load the script 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://localhost:* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

localhost/:1 Refused to load the script 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

localhost/:1 Refused to load the script 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://localhost:* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

After scratching my head and using SO:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' https://localhost:* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' https://localhost:* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
```

But it also didn't work.

Sorry if I am being stupid. I touched frontend development after a decade. What's the issue?

Comment: what csp is your server returning?

Comment: These are javascript files of a specific framework/website. These are not server from my server but rather from a trusted cdn source such as cdnjs. Its an issue with Content Security Policy from the browser. @DanielA.White

Comment: the csp is a defense mechanism where _your_ site is telling what can be loaded on it

Comment: @DanielA.White Do you mean I should add some form of headers while serving the response from the server. If so what would it be? Please provide a detailed explanation and code answer to resolve my query.

Answer (score 0):

First let's break the problem down:
You have 7 errors. The first is a style-src violation of your CSP and the rest are your 3 external scripts violation 2 different script-src directives each. Consequently there are 2 or more CSPs at play. You can define them in a meta tag as you have shown, but it could also be defined in a response header. You will need to locate all CSPs and modify them to fix your issues, as content need to pass every single CSP provided.

Your policy allows styles and scripts to load from the origin server and localhost and as inline script and style. You will need to allow the specific host names for your external sources as well, e.g. you'll need to add https://code.jquery.com or just code.jquery.com to script-src to allow loading scripts from that host.

Comment: Alright but it would have been better if you elaborated on this term and provided code samples.